# asp.net C# gridview style using CSSclass is disabled after button click

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a simple gridview with CSSClass for styling and its working fine, but the problem is when I click  a button on gridview it disable the function of the CSSClass for example after I click the button the background color is removed I don't know why,
here is my code:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"   CssClass="grid_style ">

        <Columns>
               

               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$Resources:mj.resource, item%>" ItemStyle-CssClass="Itemstyle" SortExpression="priority_id">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                             <%# 
                            Eval("[item_name_A]")

                              %>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <ItemStyle CssClass="Itemstyle1" />

                             </asp:TemplateField>

                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$Resources:mj.resource, total%>" ItemStyle-CssClass="Itemstyle" SortExpression="priority_id">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                             <%# 
                            Eval("[total]")

                              %>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <ItemStyle CssClass="Itemstyle1" />

                             </asp:TemplateField>


                            
                  <asp:TemplateField>
                       <ItemTemplate>

 <asp:linkbutton ID="Linkbutton_update" runat="server"  OnClick="update1" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("item_id") %>'  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <img src="Images/dd.png" alt="add group"  /></asp:linkbutton></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
            
            <asp:TemplateField>
                       <ItemTemplate>



                       </ItemTemplate>

                         </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
                                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString=""
            SelectCommand="SELECT * from [stock] ">



                             </asp:SqlDataSource>

 <style>
.grid_style {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
color:black;
background-color: #fff; 
text-align: center;

}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you try clearing browser cache after clicking button?

Comment: I tried it but the same problem still

Comment: Can you check HTML and verify that you don't see `grid_style` on Table?

Comment: I checked it there is no grid_style used in other table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue all I needed to do is to put the style code inside the UpdatePanel.